# Cucumber + Aruba + Windows: Tests don't see last line of stdout?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd, aruba

I'm running what should be a basic BDD demonstration using Cucumber and Aruba on Windows in Ruby 1.8.7. The idea is to have a simple "greeter" application prompt the user for a name, then say hello to them by name.

The Cucumber scenarios look like this:

```
# name_prompt.feature

Feature: Name prompt
    In order to interact with the bot
    As a friendly user
    I want to tell the app my name

    Scenario: Be asked
        Given the application is running
        Then I should see "What is your name?"

    Scenario: Talk back
        Given the application is running
        And I type "Tim" and press Enter
        Then I should see "Hello, Tim"
```

My step implementations use a few Aruba-provided functions, and looks like:

```
# cli_steps.rb

Given /^the application is running$/ do
  run_interactive(unescape("ruby chatbot.rb"))
end

Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
  assert_partial_output(arg1)
end

Given /^I type "([^"]*)" and press Enter$/ do |arg1|
  type(arg1)
end
```

The bot itself is pretty simple, and just looks like:

```
# chatbot.rb
$stdout.sync = true

puts "What is your name?"
name = gets.chomp
puts "Hello, #{name}"
```

On Mac/Linux, this works fine and passes all scenarios. On Windows, however, I'm consistently seeing that the output being tested in `assert_partial_output` doesn't include the last line (the "Hello, Tim").

I've tried using `pp` on the contents of `@interactive.stdout`, which should contain the entire output of the program, but it just contains the first "What is your name?" line, plus a line break.

Are there any issues on Windows that would cause this kind of trouble with Cucumber and Aruba? Why won't these tests pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a timing/buffer issue.

I've tried ChildProcess (the library that Aruba uses in the background) and the only difference with what Aruba does is invoke `close` on stdin. The following script works with chartbot.rb, even without stdout flush:

```
require "rubygems" unless defined?(Gem)
require "childprocess"
require "tempfile"

out = Tempfile.new "out"

process = ChildProcess.build("ruby", "chatbot.rb")
process.io.stdout = out
process.io.stderr = out
process.duplex = true

process.start
process.io.stdin.puts "Tim"
process.io.stdin.close

process.poll_for_exit 1
out.rewind
puts out.read
```

Perhaps you can report this issue to Aruba bug tracker?

https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/issues

Comment: This led me to the answer: on Windows, `@process.io.stdin.sync` needs to be set to `true` within the childprocess handler file `process.rb`.